# AngularJS: Element not found via getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I use a function of a third party JavaScript application which I include and call in one of my AngularJS factories. One parameter of this function is the id of a DOM element because the function manipulates this element.

```
ThirdPartyApp.doSomething("#elementId").then(function (success) {

                    }, function (error) {

                    });
```

But I get the error: **Unable to get element with id ...**

I assume the app uses `document.getElementById` because I tried to call it manually but it doesn't find the element even though it exists according to the DOM explorer of the browser.

The element with the id is in a HTML page which I include via ng-include.

How do I solve this problem within my AngularJS environment, since I cannot change the way the third party app works?

**MORE INFORMATION**

Here is the html page with the element:

```
<div>
    <iframe id='testId' ng-src='{{test}}' style='overflow: hidden;' />
</div>
```

Here is how I include this html page:

```
<ng-include src="'/views/shared/test.html'"></ng-include>
```

Why does `document.getElementById("testId")` in the AngularJS factory not find the iframe element?

Comment: Have you tried passing in the elementId without the `#`?

Comment: @DanielBernsons Yes. Same result

Comment: In that case, without knowledge of what third party application you are using or what your HTML code looks like, it's impossible to provide any useful help.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell exactly what might be going on here since I can't see the source code for the third party library you're using.

However, my guess is that the template you are adding with `ng-include` hasn't finished loading the content when you make the call to get the iframe element.

To verify this, try to get the element by adding the following to your AngularJS controller:

```
$scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function () {
    var myTest = document.getElementById("testId");
});
```

This block of code will wait for your "ng-included" content to render.

Comment: Sorry. Typo. It is actually in a AngularJS factory. I tried following: $rootScope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function () {
                        var myTest = document.getElementById("sketch");
                    }); But the function is never called.

Comment: Your factory is completely unaware of your template. This is logic that **needs** to be in a controller.